# Facebook get user id

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am making a simple contest on Facebook which is a form to fill in.
I would like to add a mechanism with share options.

You will win another chance for each friend who will click on the back link.

Technically i wish to add to the shared url the user id to add 1 chance for him in my database (sharing options will appear after the form)

So i need the user id but i don't want to display the FB popup "accept this application" before launching my app. Is it possible?

If not, do you have an id or online to do it with open graph and all that stuff?

Comment: Nope, you will only get the user id if you have them connect to your app first. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the User-/Facebook-ID of the user without login/authorization. The signed request variable only presents basic infos if the user is not logged in (like status, admin status, locale, ...).

So, in order to get the User ID you have to authorize the user, i recommend the JavaScript SDK for this:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

This is against the Facebook Page Terms.

You can not have a contest where sharing is considered a entry in a contest.

Follow this link and look at Section III.E.3 for details
https://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php